# Command not working in shell script, but works on command line

Tags: shell-script

I have a shell script that executes the following command:

```
bash -c "screen -dmS node /home/nodejs/bridge/bridge.js"
```

However, the screen is not being started. Typing the command...

```
screen -dmS node /home/nodejs/bridge/bridge.js
```

...in a terminal(logged as the same user that launches the script) the screen starts up properly.

Comment: What is the output when you're running your script ?

Comment: Have you tried using `/usr/bin/screen` instead of `screen`?

Comment: Where do you execute the shell script from? From a terminal? If you're running the script from a session startup hook, which one? Why do you run `bash -c "screen …"` rather than `screen …` directly?

Answer (score 0):

With screen you probably need a login shell.

```
bash --login -c "screen -dmS node /home/nodejs/bridge/bridge.js"
```